Avsc (avro implementation in Javascript) not being able to use records that use the "bytes" type field
I am using a lib https://github.com/mtth/avsc to work with avro em nodeJs but i have some complications
Has anyone here suffered from the problem of not being able to use records that use the "bytes" type field? I've already tried passing the information in byte format to the registry in many different ways (Uint8Array, Buffer, TextEncoder) but all without success
npm install avsc
const avro = require('avsc');

const type = avro.Type.forSchema({
    type: 'record',
    name: 'Pet',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'payload', type: 'bytes' },
    ]
});

const AVRO_RECORD = {
    name: 'Douglas',
    payload: new TextEncoder().encode('This is a string')
}

try {
    const buf = type.toBuffer(AVRO_RECORD); // Encoded buffer.
    const val = type.fromBuffer(buf); // AVRO_RECORD { name: 'Douglas', payload: .....}
    console.log('VALUE', val)
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e) //"Error: invalid 'bytes': {'0':84,'1':104,'2':105,'3':115,'4':32,'5':105,'6':115,'7':32,'8':97,'9':32,'10':115,'11':116,'12':114,'13':105,'14':110,'15':103}

}

CodePen
I've already tried passing the information in byte format to the registry in many different ways (Uint8Array, Buffer, TextEncoder) but all without success

Not being able roundtrip a value looks like a clear bug to me. Have you tried reporting it in the library issue tracker?

Works for me when I use Buffer.from(<string>, <encoding>), like so:
const AVRO_RECORD = {
    name: 'Douglas',
    payload: Buffer.from('This is a string', 'utf-8')
}

try {
    const buf = type.toBuffer(AVRO_RECORD); // Encoded buffer.
    const val = type.fromBuffer(buf); // AVRO_RECORD { name: 'Douglas', payload: .....}
    console.log('VALUE', val)
    console.log( 'Decoded payload', val.payload.toString('utf-8') )
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e) //"Error: invalid 'bytes': {'0':84,'1':104,'2':105,'3':115,'4':32,'5':105,'6':115,'7':32,'8':97,'9':32,'10':115,'11':116,'12':114,'13':105,'14':110,'15':103}

}

